# Wait for the return of the loop on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below, the form is needed to be validated before it can submit the form.
But the problem is, the form continues to submit without validating.

```
<form action='#' method='post' onsubmit='return validate();'>

function validate()
{
    $('form').find(':input:not(:submit,:hidden), select, textarea').each(function(e)
    {       
        $(this).removeClass('redBox');
        var rq = $(this).attr('requiredz');

        if(rq != undefined)
        {
            if($(this).val().trim() == '')
            {
                $(this).addClass('redBox');
                $("#errorMsg").html('Red boxes cannont be left empty!');
                return false;
            }               
        }       
    });
});
```

How to handle the return of a loop?
Dont submit the form once encountered return false on the loop.

Comment: The `return` statement in your code belongs to the `each`'s callback.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function validate()
{
    var passes = true;
    $('form').find(':input:not(:submit,:hidden), select, textarea').each(function(e)
    {       
        $(this).removeClass('redBox');
        var rq = $(this).attr('requiredz');

        if(rq != undefined)
        {
            if($(this).val().trim() == '')
            {
                $(this).addClass('redBox');
                $("#errorMsg").html('Red boxes cannont be left empty!');
                passes = false;
            }               
        }       
    });

    return passes;
});
```

Comment: ah! I already have that on my mind but didn't tried. And now you've suggested that's why I tried and work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use return.

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function(event){
    if (validate() === false) {
        event.preventDefault(); // like return false;
    }
});
```

For more information see [jQuery submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Each function has it's own returned value, the default returned value is an `undefined` value. You should check the length of the invalid elements after the `each` loop and return a proper value, since you are using jQuery I'd suggest:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) 
{
    var $invalid = $(this)
                    .find(':input:not(:submit,:hidden), select, textarea')
                    .removeClass('redBox')
                    .addClass(function () {
                       return this.getAttribute('requiredz') 
                              && $.trim(this.value) === ''
                              ? 'redBox' 
                              : null;
                    }).filter('.redBox');

    if ($invalid.length) 
    {
        $("#errorMsg").html('Red boxes cannont be left empty!');
        return false;
    }

});
```